# Infinite Loop When Testing - Interface Call

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a problem when testing Solidity smart contracts, when they use an interface call to another smart contract. I have reduced the code to the following. This is the MainContract

```
pragma solidity = 0.8.11;

import 'contracts/test/IOtherContract.sol';

contract MainContract {
    address public immutable otherContract;

    constructor(address _otherContract) public {
        otherContract = _otherContract;
    }

    function callOtherContract(address wallet) external returns (address pair){
        pair = IOtherContract(otherContract).checkAddress(wallet);
        return pair;
    }
}
```

OtherContract

```
pragma solidity = 0.8.11;

import 'contracts/test/IOtherContract.sol';

contract OtherContract is IOtherContract{
    mapping(address => address) public checkAddress;

    function addAddress(address wallet) external override{
        checkAddress[wallet] = wallet;
    }
}
```

The interface

```
pragma solidity = 0.8.11;

interface IOtherContract{
    function checkAddress(address wallet) external returns (address pair);
    function addAddress(address wallet) external;
}
```

Test script

```
const { waffle } = require('hardhat');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
const { expect } = require('chai');

const { Contract, Wallet, BigNumber } = ethers;
const { MockProvider, deployContract } = waffle;

const overrides = {
    gasLimit: 13000000
};

describe('TestInterface', () => {
    let mainContractContract;
    let otherContractContract;
    let mainContract;
    let otherContract;

    it('test', async () => {
        const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
        let owner = signers[0];

        mainContractContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MainContract");
        otherContractContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("OtherContract");

        otherContract = await otherContractContract.deploy();
        mainContract = await mainContractContract.deploy(otherContract.address);

        let pair = await mainContract.callOtherContract(owner.address);
        
    });
});
```

When I run this code using hardhat version 2.8.3 I get the following error

```
Error: Timeout of 12000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/einezahl/dev/crypto/cybar-finance/cybar-swap-periphery/test/testInterface.spec.ts)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

When I deploy the contract and interact with it I have no problems. Can anyone explain this behavior?
I have tried different solidity versions and changed the checkAddress to a getter function, nothing has worked yet.

**update:**
Ok, the contract calls also don't work when I deploy it to a local hardhat node. A similar contract worked when I deployed it to a ganache instance.

Comment: The solidity code is fine, so the problem should be somewhere else. There are a few warnings about using "public" in the constructor and overriding `checkAddress`.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with hardhat or waffle, I reduced the code further such that it only contains a mapping and the test gets an element of the mapping. This fails when using hardhat but works when using remix.